# allow users to change their own password, email and Profile

Tags: symfony1, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

I'm creating my own blog engine to learn Symfony, and I have a question :

I can add and edit users thanks to the *sfGuardUser* module, but how can I allow users to edit only their reccord ?

Users should have access to a page allowing them to edit their email, name, password, and Profile.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following code, will try it tonight.

```
class sfGuardUserActions extends autoSfGuardUserActions {


    public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $this->checkPerm($request);
        parent::executeEdit($request);
    }

    public function checkPerm(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $id = $request->getParameter('id');

        $user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
        $user_id = $user->getGuardUser()->getId();

        if ($id != $user_id && !($user->hasCredential('admin'))) {
            $this->redirect('sfGuardAuth/secure');
        }
    } }
```

from http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/96776/

Comment: This works by forbidding users to edit another user's profile, but it doesn't save the user info correctly

Answer (score 0):

In the action where the profile is updated you retrieve the users object via the `getId()` method and apply the changes on the returning object.

```
$user = sfGuardUserPeer::retrieveByPK(
  $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId()
);
```